# java null pointer exception setting my action bar and fragment in my page viewer via button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a page viewer as my main display page and i have used codes from the java class itself to create my tabs and action bar like this:

```
protected ViewPager viewPager;
private pageAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Home", "BroadCast", "Friends" };

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new pageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (String tab_name : tabs)
        {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
```

i have three fragments for each tab that is loaded to the page viewer but on a particular fragment i want to set orload a another fragment into the page viewer when a button is clicked like so:

```
main mainly = new main();

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.blastbut:
            mactv = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blastarea); 
            new postotimeline().execute();
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pageAdapter mAdapter = new pageAdapter(mainly.getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            Log.i("Blast", "Blasting");
            //send getText to database and update list view
            break;
        case R.id.sf:
            break;
        case R.id.blastarea:
            break;
    }

}
```

but it keeps giving me a null pointer exception on the `viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);` i have tried various ways but it keeps giving me the java null pointer exception.
Please I am not so much of a professional in android. so kindly excuse me if i missed the obvious.

Log cat:

```
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Process: example.gbaalert, PID: 1119
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at example.gbaalert.broadcastfragment.onClick(broadcastfragment.java:75)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-20 05:15:35.785: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NOTE:  main is a Fragment Activity that implements tab listener that is bind to a page viewer(XML) and the class in which the button is clicked extends a Fragment

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: Please shoot yourself for using Hungarian notation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `mainly` anywhere.

And you are using it here :

`pageAdapter mAdapter = new pageAdapter(mainly.getSupportFragmentManager());`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i declared the mainly variable but i just didnt add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What is `main`?

```
main mainly = new main();

    pageAdapter mAdapter = new pageAdapter(mainly.getSupportFragmentManager());
```

These two lines suggest it's some kind of `Activity`. You cannot instantiate activities with `new` - they will not be initialized for anything practical. The code here is a little lacking in context, but I think you can call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` here i.e. remove the `mainly.`, replacing with `getActivity()` and also remove and the first line where you attempt to instantiate the activity.

Comment: main is an activity that is bind to a page viewer and the class in which the button is clicked extends a Fragment and the getSupportFragmentManager() does not work in a class that extends Fragment

Answer (score 0):

If the line 
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
is causing your NULL - Pointer Exception, then the view with id R.id.pager cannot be found.
This may happen when you didn't call setContentView within your activity or the layout you are using doesn't contain the View.

(Edited)

Comment: I know that but how do i get the getSupportFragmentManager() to work without a red underline or it returning null

Comment: Well: How is your main - class defined?

Comment: this is my main class that has the first portion of codes posted above `public class main extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {}`

Comment: Okay, but this looks fine. So getSupportFragmentManager should never return null.

Comment: Ups, I oversaw it. Yes, ofcourse the line viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter); can arise a NULL - Pointer Exception. If this.getView().findViewById returns null, obviously. So while your R.id.pager is defined (it is generated at compile - time, still the view / layout containing it may not be loaded into your activity's context. So e.g. if you not called setContentView in your activity or the view you are setting as content view doesn't contain your pager.

Comment: The basic thing i need to do to solve this error is how am going to get a resource id pager from layoutA.xml which is binded to layoutA.java from layoutB.xml binded to layoutB.java. i.e. from layoutB.java i wish to access a resource id from layoutA.xml